# Jasper report PDF in hindi

Tags: java, jasper-reports, hindi

Following code is used to generate PDF file. We have some static content and some dynamic content in Hindi. Hindi content is not rendered on PDF at all. I have put jasperreports-fonts-5.5.1 jar as in classpath also. SansSerif font is being used in JRXML and deployed in tomcat.

**Shows properly in English**

[image: Shows properly in English]

**Complete Hindi content is not visible**

[image: Complete Hindi content is not visible]

```
JasperReport js = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(<JRXML URL>);

        byte[] bytes = JasperRunManager.runReportToPdf(js, parameterMap,
                new JsonDataSource(location,"studentReport"));

        String filePath = "/var/www/webdav/pdf/" + studentId + ".pdf";

        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(new File(filePath));

        fos.write(bytes, 0, bytes.length);
        fos.flush();
        fos.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Lohit Hindi` font for the static or dynamic fields having 'Hindi' values. Give a try. It may work.

Comment: Any other alternative?