# How can I render hindi correctly when exporting to pdf?

Tags: fonts, jasper-reports, export-to-pdf, hindi

I am using i-report 5.5.0 for jasper reports. I need to export Hindi text into PDF format, but Hindi part is getting converted to `???????`.

I have already used font extension but it didn't helped:

> **font name**: "lohit Devanagari" 
>  **PDF embedded**: checked 
>  **PDF
>   encoding**:Identity-H

I have also tried other Hindi fonts but nothing worked so far..

```
<textField>
    <reportElement x="111" y="26" width="100" height="20" uuid="5a471a16-de7b-4f55-9c9f-b01d37938b9f"/>
     <textElement>
        <font fontName="Lohit Devanagari" pdfEncoding="Identity-H" isPdfEmbedded="false"/>
    </textElement>
    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{DISTRICT_NAME}]]></textFieldExpression>
</textField>
```

Comment: Did you use the [font extensions](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/sample.reference/fonts/index.html#fontextensions)?

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Creating Hindi PDF using UTF-8 in JasperReport](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21532766/876298) & [Hindi Fonts in JasperReports](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23978392/876298) & [Jasper report PDF in hindi](http://stackoverflow.com/q/27819886/876298)

Comment: @AlexK, the possible duplicates do not have answers or accepted answer, user has tried font extension, see question (probably not correctly or ttf font not able to render the uni-code), this is why I have posted an answer.

Comment: This posts contains usefull comments and answers

Comment: Anyone found a way to resolve this?

Comment: @PriyeshMishra I tried most of what all you have mentioned, except that mine is not a Maven project so I added .jar as libs and external JAR, but neither helped solve the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct way to go is using [font-extensions](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/sample.reference/fonts/index.html#fontextensions). `pdfEncoding="Identity-H"` is **deprecated**.

First clear this [checklist to render font in pdf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34041619/jasper-reports-pdf-doesnt-export-cyrillic-values/34044441#34044441):

1. Is my actual `.tff` **supported** ([OpenType](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenType)) and can the font actually **render** the character. Not all fonts render
   all characters in `UTF-8`

> Once you have created correctly font extension and its not working this is probably your problem..

2. Do I pass **correct encoding** to iText. In doubts (or in general) use
   the encoding **Identity-H** this is recommend for newer PDF standards
   and gives you the ability to mix different encoding.

> Identity-H seems ok

3. Is my font **embedded** so that if I share the pdf also computers not
   having this font can display the content.

> Embed your font (otherwise if you make it work on your computer it may
>   not work on others), note in your jrxml is `isPdfEmbedded=false`, remove tag and in font-extension select `true` or set tag to `true`.

Now just generate the **font-extension** correctly and add it to your `classpath`,

[How to add font extensions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33940126/how-can-i-display-%C2%A3%E2%84%A6%E2%82%AC%CE%B1%CF%80%E2%85%94-in-jasperserver-pdf-using-ireport/33941102#33941102)

**EDIT: After user passed font**

The font `Krutidev_011.TTF` is not a valid ttf font it maybe because unfortunately the standard according to Apple and the standard according to Microsoft diverged (my guess your font is an apple ttf not an open type ttf).

```
Caused by: net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRRuntimeException: java.awt.FontFormatException: java.nio.BufferUnderflowException
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fonts.SimpleFontFace.setTtf(SimpleFontFace.java:178)
```

I tried to [download](http://www.ffonts.net/Lohit-Devanagari.font.download) a valid ttf font **Lohit Devanagari** from the web and add it as font extension, `fontName="Lohit Devanagari"` this is my result:

[image: fontTest]

It is rendering the fonts but the result may have **Ligaturizer problem**, for how to solve these see for example [Why is the Gujarati-Indian text not rendered correctly using Arial Unicode MS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36655923/why-is-the-gujarati-indian-text-not-rendered-correctly-using-arial-unicode-ms)

If you like to try this is the font-extension I used [font extension jar for Lohit Devanagari](http://www.jdd.it/stacktrace/LohitDevanagariExtension.jar), remember to set `fontName="Lohit Devanagari"`

Comment: my actual .tff is rendering the word correctly and when i export to other format it works well(like in HTML, ODT ,EXCEL) only PDF export is creating problem

Comment: Can you share the jar of your font extension? and your jrxml (or a small jrxml with text not displaying to test your font extension)?

Comment: Jar file :-http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=03986171897156283365

Jrxml:-<textField>
    <reportElement x="146" y="0" width="89" height="20" uuid="59ea6b83-7961-47d7-9e0a-b3e9dae6476b"/>
    <textElement>
     <font fontName="Kruti Dev 011" pdfEncoding="Identity-H" isPdfEmbedded="true"/>
    </textElement>
    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{DISTRICT_NAME_HINDI}]]></textFieldExpression>
   </textField>

Comment: @Priyesh Mishra I have edit the answer, your TTF is not valid (this depends on the fact that there exists different TTF types....), check edit

Comment: Sir, i have downloaded your jar file and set class path ,used font name = lohit devnagri this was the result :- 
Error exporting print... Identity-H 
ExceptionConverter: java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException: Identity-H      at java.lang.StringCoding.encode(StringCoding.java:340)      at java.lang.String.getBytes(String.java:955)

Comment: @Priyesh Mishra The problem is probably because you already have another definition of "Lohit Devanagari" try this find out; download this font extension http://www.jdd.it/stacktrace/LohitDevanagari_EXT.jar and use fontName="Lohit Devanagari Ext", it will not work in iReport but if you set classpath your export should work.

Comment: when i used LohitDevnagri_EXT output was :- at org.openide.util.RequestProcessor$Processor.run(RequestProcessor.java:997)  net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.JRFontNotFoundException: Font 'Lohit Devanagari Ext' is not available to the JVM. See the Javadoc for more details.  and PDF was not generarted

Comment: one more thing i want to mention that i am using DB2 as database and table column field is VARGRAPHICS .Can this cause a problem??

Comment: "Font 'Lohit Devanagari‌​ Ext' is not available to the JVM", you have not added the LohitDevanagari_EXT.jar  to your class path, refeering to VARGRAPHICS, test first with some simple example (to solve font problem) then move one to VARGRAPHICS, you should not write code that should write code that contain special characters, its better to use  notations es.  \u010c, but I think this is a secondary problem

Comment: Thanks a lot sir.i used jasper studio software and report worked fine . i think there was some problem with PDF encoding in i-report 5.5. btw problem still persists when i use my web application for report output .

Comment: @Priyesh Mishra Add the font extension jar in web application

Comment: added to .m2 folder and created dependency in pom.xml but not working

Comment: Be sure that the correct font extension jar is in classpath (or include the font .tff, fontFamilies.xml, jasperreports_extension.properties directly in your project.)

Comment: added correct font extension file in my web application still no use

Comment: Problem got resolved when i attached jar file as an external . Thank you so much for your help and guidance

Comment: @PetterFriberg could you please post the sample jrxml and jar?

Comment: @Sumit the jar I used is already in post (the links is still up), as for as example I'm not sure what you expect just set `fontName="Lohit Devanagari"` if you use that jar.

Comment: @PetterFriberg Could you take a look at what I am doing wrong possibly? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44428641/jrxml-hindi-text-to-pdf

Comment: @Sumit I did and I saw your feedback on this answer, just wondering why, if you care to share.

Answer (score 2):

this worked for me

```
IndicLigaturizer  hindi = new DevanagariLigaturizer();
String result = hindi.process(string);
```

Comment: Thank you I wasted days on this.

Answer (score 0):

I have same problem I solve it with gargi.ttf font. [download here](https://github.com/byrongibson/fonts/blob/master/truetype/ttf-indic-fonts-core/gargi.ttf)
with this configuration

```
"gargi" => array(
        'R' => "gargi.ttf",
        'useOTL' => 0xFF,
    ),
```

Answer (score 0):

Jasper Report:- You can use **Arial Unicode MS** for Hindi and same font jar include in java build path

[Jasper Font Arial Unicode MS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9bL9X.png)

[Arial unicode jar exported from ireport tool import in STS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MBWGQ.png)

[Output same as input](https://i.stack.imgur.com/52e6C.png)