# how to write UTF-8 (persian) characters in jsp

Tags: java, jsp, jasper-reports, report

```
<%@page import="com.itextpdf.text.Font"%>
<%@ page contentType="application/pdf"%>
<%@page trimDirectiveWhitespaces="true"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.Connection"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.DriverManager"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.SQLException"%>
<%@page import="java.util.HashMap"%>
<%@page import="java.util.Map"%>
<%@page import="java.io.FileOutputStream"%>
<%@page import="java.io.FileNotFoundException"%>
<%@page import="java.io.InputStream"%>
<%@page import="java.io.File"%>
<%@page import="java.io.FileInputStream"%>
<%@page import="net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperExportManager"%>
<%@page import="net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperCompileManager"%>
<%@page import="net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager"%>
<%@page import="net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperPrint"%>
<%@page import="net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperReport"%>
<%
    Connection conne = null;
    try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    conne = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/west-az-1540", "root", "123456");
    String jrxmlFile = session.getServletContext().getRealPath("/karAmouzi.jrxml");
    InputStream input = new FileInputStream(new File(jrxmlFile));
    JasperReport jasperReport = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(input);
    JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport, null, conne);
    JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfStream(jasperPrint, response.getOutputStream());
    response.getOutputStream().flush();
    response.getOutputStream().close();

} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} finally {
    if (conne != null) {
        conne.close();
    }
}
%>
```

this is a program that reads data from database and shows them in a .jrxml file. when I run it in doesent show persian caracters.

jaspersoft preview:
[image]

browser preview:
[image]

Comment: I think you should embed font in pdf.  But I don't know how to do.

Comment: It is called font-extension, see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34287186/jasper-report-hindi-pdf and this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33940126/how-can-i-display-%C2%A3%E2%84%A6%E2%82%AC%CE%B1%CF%80%E2%85%94-in-jasperserver-pdf-using-ireport/33941102#33941102

Comment: If you have troubles let me know.. There is alot of links on SO on font-extensions.