# Not able to render hindi fonts as desired using Intervention Library with imagick driver

Tags: laravel, intervention

I'm using [Intervention](http://image.intervention.io/) Library for laravel with imagick.
it doesn't render Hindi fonts correctly.

For example:
"इण्टरनेट पर हिन्दी के साधन" is getting rendered as [image]

Here is my code. I'm using **Arial-unicode-ms** font

```
public static function generateOverlayText($image, $text)
{
    $img = Image::make($image->getContent());
    $extension = 'jpg';
    $centerX = 25;
    $centerY = 210;
    $lines = explode("\n", wordwrap($text, 21));
    $currentLineVIndex = $centerY;

    foreach ($lines as $line) {
        $img->text($line, $centerX, $currentLineVIndex, function ($font) use ($fontSize) {
            $font->file(public_path('fonts/arial-unicode-ms/arial-uni.ttf'));
            $font->size(18);
            $font->color('#fdf6e3');
        });

    }
    $encoded = $img->encode($extension);
    return $encoded;
}
```

Can we do something to render it correctly?
Thanks for the help

Comment: This answer might help https://stackoverflow.com/a/34287509/3500359